Blazor WASM and EntraID authentication
I'm learning Blazor and trying to interact with Azure EntraID to protect some pages. At this point was able to achieve that.
My question is related to "@context.User.Identity?.Name"... As I'm connected to EntraID, some user details will be useful for some features, for example e-mail address. But I can't find anywhere to enable context to bring other values from EntraID instead just Name.
Please, how can I retrieve other user details to be part of my code on other pages? Anyone have a guide to achieve that?
Thanks!
Reviewed every file in the project to locate @context, but no success until now.

You could go to Azure EntraId - App Registrations - Your App - Manage - Token Configuration - Add optional claims. Add Email claim to IdToken for the user.

var email = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email")?.Value;


Hi, did the changes on Azure side, but when add the code got "The name 'User' does not exist in the current context".  Also, forgot to mention, that I starting from WebAssembly template using Microsoft Identity Platform.
